# In memory web page browsing

Tags: web, screen-scraping

Is their any way to execute load events of javascript of web page after scraping html, without any browser. i.e. I need to scrape web content rendered via javascript for example vedio of bbc news web page are rendered via javacscript after page load, i am interested to scrape video link and shot description. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/

Answer (score 0):

**No**, as far as I know. If the content is rendered by Javascript, you need a browser. It is possible to automate a browser: http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: But the problem with seleniummhq is this is a tool it must be operated but I need a way so that I could collect html source generated after load events executed completed.

Answer (score 0):

I often do this using webkit:
http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://sitescraper.net'  
r = Render(url)  
html = r.frame.toHtml()
```

Comment: I would suggest to use PhantomJs (https://phantomjs.org/) or yslow (http://yslow.org/), that will help you to wait for the full html to load.